# Unable to iterate through template map. How to deal with this error?

Tags: c++

I have a graph class that employs two dimension vertices using a map with another map nested inside, as such(V is my template):

```
map< V , map<  V , int> > vertices;
```

Defining an iterator as such seems to be ok:

```
typename map< V, map< V , int>::iterator i;
```

However when I try to use that iterator, like this `i = vertices.begin()` , I get a long error that looks like this. (main.cpp 81 is where I call the method that does the iteration). Where could I look at to find what's wrong?

```
main.cpp:81:   instantiated from here
graph.h:326: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘i = ((const GraphNameSpace::Graph<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >*)this)->GraphNameSpace::Graph<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,      std::allocator<char> > >::vertices.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::begin [with _Key = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, _Tp = std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > >, _Compare = std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > > >]()’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_tree.h:152: note: candidates are: std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > > >& std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > > >::operator=(const std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, int> > > > >&)
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

UPDATE:
At the risk of providing too much information, here is my [graph class on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/TW5QM74Q). Right at the very bottom in the `dump` function is where I'm attempting to do the iteration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The member function `dump()`, inside which you write `i = vertices.begin()`,  is a `const` member function, which effectively makes `vertices` a `const` object, for it is a member of the class. So you need `const_iterator`:

```
typename map<V, map<V, int> >::const_iterator i;
                             //^^^^^ note this
```

It should work now. :-)